# Facebook login not dismissing the webpage.

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am using a custom button for my Facebook login. When I click the button a webpage inside the app opens the facebook page with login with app or email/phone. I click open in app, and go through the process. After that process, I get redirected to my app, but the webpage still appears, and is not dismiss.

```
@IBAction func loginFacebookAction(sender: AnyObject) {//action of the custom button in the storyboard
        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    //everything works print the user data
                    print(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am not understanding which webpage still you see after you redirect! can you show snapshot of it?

Comment: The page that first appears when you click the button on the app. When you click "login with facebook" on the app it opens a webpage with the option to "log in with the facebook app" or "log in with phone or email". I am able to click open in app, and it works, but after I authorize it redirects me to the webpage and does not dismiss it.

Comment: What i remind is there should be  DONE button at top left of screen ?? is it there ?? if its there you still want to dismiss automatically?

Comment: Yes there is a DONE button at the top left of the screen. It should dismiss automatically, but it isn't

Comment: ok, you wish it to webpage to automatically get dismissed after completion/approval by facebook! Right?

Comment: Have you implemented  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error method ??

Comment: Yes and would I have to implement FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate since I am using a custom button?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add configuration in my AppDelegate https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios